# Grouping certain columns on a union on 2 tables returns one of the two randomly

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE 1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 1 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 01:00:00 | 2 | 22 |
| 2021-01-01 02:00:00 | 1 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 03:00:00 | 6 | 20 |
| 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | 22 |

TABLE 2

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 | 9 | 22 |

I have 2 very big tables in the given format with A and C as their primary keys. Every time I run the following query, I get one of the two union rows randomly instead of getting the first one just like in the example. Why does it behave that way and how can I change the query so that I will always get the first row in the union result unless table1 doesn't have that date? (using only union and no joins)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (
  SELECT Date(A) as 'Date', SUM(B) as 'B', C FROM TABLE1
    WHERE Date(A) = '2021-01-01'
    AND C = 20
    GROUP BY A, C
  ) 
UNION
  (
  SELECT A, SUM(B) as 'B', C FROM TABLE2
    WHERE A = '2021-01-01'
    AND C = 20
    GROUP BY A, C
  )
)d
GROUP BY d.Date , d.C;
```

UNION RESULT

| Date | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 8 | 20 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 20 |

QUERY RESULT

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 8 | 20 |

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid it like this

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  (
  SELECT Date(A) as 'Date', SUM(B) as 'B', C, 1 AS 'Sort' FROM TABLE1
    WHERE Date(A) = '2021-01-01'
    AND C = 20
    GROUP BY A, C
  ) 
UNION
  (
  SELECT A, SUM(B) as 'B', C, 2 FROM TABLE2
    WHERE A = '2021-01-01'
    AND C = 20
    GROUP BY A, C
  )
) d
ORDER BY d.Sort
GROUP BY d.Date , d.C;
```

Comment: I've tried sorting inside the subquery but it doesn't work

Comment: You have to sort outside. inside the subquery you don't have the data from both tables

Comment: It's not possible to order it before group by and ordering it after affects only the visuals. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could wrap it once more. Something like `SELECT * FROM d ( SELECT * FROM e ( SELECT [..] UNION SELECT [...] ) e ORDER BY e.Sort) GROUP BY d.Date, d.C

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a condition that the `select` query on the second table should only return records if the 1st table doesn't return anything for your `where` condition

```
SELECT Date(A) as 'Date', SUM(B) as 'B', C
FROM t1
WHERE Date(A) = '2021-01-01' AND 
      C = 20 
GROUP BY Date(A), C

UNION

SELECT A, SUM(B) as 'B', C
FROM t2
WHERE A = '2021-01-01' AND  
      C = 20 AND
      (select count(*) from t1 where Date(A) = '2021-01-01' AND  C = 20) = 0
GROUP BY A, C;
```